# Is there an no-op (pass-through) operation in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

As per title. I'd like to make use of such operation to rename the nodes and better organize a graph. Or is there other recommended practice for renaming an existing node in the graph? Thanks!

Comment: for the sake of completeness, there is a `tf.no_op` https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#no_op but i think you want a passthrough op like `tf.identity`

Comment: after some exploring, i found using `collections` to be much more helpful than renaming. check out the examples here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/meta_graph/index.html

Comment: `tf.no_op` link is a 404, here is the updated one: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/no_op

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot rename a Tensor once created.

However, you can use additional "no-op" operations (like you said):

- for a `tf.Tensor`: `tf.identity(input_tensor, name='your_new_name')`
- for an operation: `tf.group(input_operation, name='your_new_name')`

---

After that, you can call the `input_tensor` with:

```py
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
graph.get_tensor_by_name('your_new_name:0')
```

Or the `input_operation` with:

```py
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
graph.get_operation_by_name('your_new_name')
```

Answer (score 19):

There is [`tf.no_op`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/no_op) which allows you to add an operation which does nothing.