# Can I change Inv operation into Reciprocal in an existing graph in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am working on an image classification problem with tensorflow. I have 2 different CNNs trained separately (in fact 3 in total but I will deal with the third later), for different tasks and on a AWS (Amazon) machine. One tells if there is text in the image and the other one tells if the image is safe for work or not. Now I want to use them in a single script on my computer, so that I can put an image as input and get the results of both networks as output.

I load the two graphs in a single tensorflow Session, using the `import_meta_graph` API and the import_scope argument and putting each subgraph in a separate scope. Then I just use the `restore` method of the created saver, giving it the common Session as argument.

Then, in order to run inference, I retrieve the placeholders and final output with `graph=tf.get_default_graph()` and `my_var=graph.get_operation_by_name('name').outputs[0]` before using it in `sess.run` (I think I could just have put 'name' in `sess.run` instead of fetching the output tensor and putting it in a variable, but this is not my problem).

**My problem is** the text CNN works perfectly fine, but the nsfw detector always gives me the same output, no matter the input (even with `np.zeros()`). I have tried both separately and same story: text works but not nsfw. So I don't think the problem comes from using two networks simultaneaously.

I also tried on the original AWS machine I trained it on, and this time the nsfw CNN worked perfectly.

Both networks are very similar. I checked on [Tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwv6S.png) if everything was fine and I think it is ok. The differences are in the number of hidden units and the fact that I use batch normalization in the nsfw model and not in the text one. Now **why this title** ? I observed that I had a warning when running the nsfw model that I didn't have when using only the text model:

> W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:332] Op Inv is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 17. Use Reciprocal.

So I thougt maybe this was the reason, everything else being equal. I checked my GraphDef version, which seems to be 11, so Inv should still work in theory. By the way the AWS machine use tensroflow version 0.10 and I use version 0.12.

I noticed that the text network only had one Inv operation (via a filtering on the names of the operations given by `graph.get_operations()`), and that the nsfw model had the same operation plus multiple Inv operations due to the batch normalization layers. As precised in the [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases), `tf.inv` has simply been renamed to `tf.reciprocal`, so I tried to change the names of the operations to Reciprocal with `tf.group()`, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949588/is-there-an-no-op-pass-through-operation-in-tensorflow), but it didn't work. I have seen that using `tf.identity()` and changing the name could also work, but from what I understand, tensorflow graphs are an append-only structure, so we can't really modify its operations (which seems to be immutable anyway).

**The thing is**:

1. as I said, the Inv operation should still work in my GraphDef version;
2. this is only a warning;
3. the Inv operations only appear under name scopes that begin with 'gradients' so, from my understanding, this shouldn't be used for inference;
4. the text model also have an Inv operation.

For these reasons, I have a big doubt on my diagnosis. So **my final questions are**:

- do you have another diagnosis?
- if mine is correct, is it possible to replace Inv operations with Reciprocal operations, or do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

After a thorough examination of the output of relevant nodes, with the help of Tensorboard, I am now pretty certain that the renaming of Inv to Reciprocal has nothing to do with my problem.

It appears that the last batch normalization layer eliminates almost any variance of its output when the inputs varies. I will ask why elsewhere.